# How can I refer to an object while creating another object in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I've been trying to build an app and for brevity, assuming that I only have two types of objects with the following fields:

1. User: user_uid, name, Settings(reference)
2. Settings: settings_uid, some_settings_json

So far, I've tried creating *Settings* object first then linking the ready *Settings* object to the *User* object getting created.

Creating the settings object:

```
mutation createSettings {
  createSettings(data: {some_settings_json: "{"some_key": "some_value"}" }) {
    settings_uid
  }
}
```

Creating the User object:

```
mutation createUser {
  createUser(data: {name: "some_user", settings: <SETTINGS_OBJECT>) {
    user_uid
  }
}
```

Although I've checked documentations, tutorials, web; I haven't been able to figure out how to replace `<SETTINGS_OBJECT>`, so that these two objects would get linked. Note: I don't want to create settings while user is getting created. For that, a tutorial already provides an example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The link is provided via `connect` keyword.

```
mutation createUser {
  createUser(data: {
    name: "some_name", settings: {
      connect: {
        settings_uid: "settings_uid"
      }
    }
  }) {
    user_uid
  }
}
```